# Testing if finish() is called in an instrumentation test

Tags: android, android-testing

The activity being tested is for a simple board game. When the conditions necessary for the game to be over are met, after doing several things to display who won etc, the following code is run:

```
// Return to main menu after 5 seconds
Handler h = new Handler();
h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        finish();
    }
}, 5000);
```

I have an instrumentation test which uses `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`. I can manufacture it so that the test starts with the board one move away from the above code being called. But after doing that move how can I assert that `finish()` was called?

I've tried duplicating this test using an `ActivityUnitTestCase` which has the `isFinishCalled()` method, but I haven't been able to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

I have 2 possible solution for this problem:

1. Rewrite the test as Unit test with [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) framework:

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
       ........

       public void finishGame() {
           Handler h = new Handler();
           h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   finish();
               }
           }, 5000);
       }
   }
   ```

   Then the test will look like:

   ```
   @RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
   @Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk=21)
   public class MainActivityTest {

       @Test
       public void testFinishing() throws InterruptedException {
           MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();

           assertFalse(mainActivity.isFinishing());

           mainActivity.finishGame();
           ShadowLooper.runUiThreadTasksIncludingDelayedTasks();

           assertTrue(mainActivity.isFinishing());
       }
   }
   ```
2. Avoid `Handler` in unit tests only:

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
       ........

       public void finishGame(boolean postDelayed) {
           if (postDelayed) {
               Handler h = new Handler();
               h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       finish();
                   }
               }, 5000);

               return;
           }

           finish();
       }
   }
   ```

   Then the test will look like:

   ```
   public class MainActivityTest extends ActivityTestCase {

       public MainActivityTest() {
           super();
           setActivity(new MainActivity());
       }

       public void testFinishing() {
           assertFalse(getActivity().isFinishing());
           ((MainActivity)getActivity()).finishGame(false);
           assertTrue(getActivity().isFinishing());
       }
   }
   ```

   And in production code you call this method like `finishGame(true)`.

In my project, I'm sticking to the second option (in my case, I'm testing `FragmentTransaction`'s behavior, with also required delay for ensuring the view is properly constructed)

I hope, it helps